# Embedded Pig in Java with Cassandra: Can't look backwards more than one token in stream

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-pig

I am running a pig (0.9.1) script from Java in local mode that gets records from Cassandra (1.0.6). The script is:

```
rows = LOAD 'cassandra://Keyspace/Data' USING CassandraStorage() AS (key, columns: bag {T: tuple(name, value)});
cols = FOREACH rows GENERATE flatten(columns);
colnames = FOREACH cols GENERATE $0;
namegroups = GROUP colnames BY (chararray) $0;
namecounts = FOREACH namegroups GENERATE COUNT($1), group;
orderednames = ORDER namecounts BY $0;
topnames = LIMIT orderednames 50;
dump topnames;
```

Whenever I try to run the script, I get:

```
org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: Error during parsing. can't look backwards more than one token in this stream
```

Interestingly, when I run a pig script that just reads and writes the filesystem (no Cassandra), it works fine. I am using the CassandraStorage file that comes with Cassandra.

Any ideas? Thanks.